# Finding a person who has eaten apples but has not eaten bananas

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, subquery

I would like to device an SQLite query that finds out whether a person with a certain `person_id` has eaten the `Fruit` `'apple'` but not the fruit `'banana'`. I have access to a `Fruit` table that contains information on who has eaten which type of fruit. I would then like to use this information to `SELECT` the last name of the person who ate `apple`s but not `banana`s with a subquery.
In my mind it would go something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  P.last_name
FROM
  Person AS P
WHERE
  P.pid IN (
    SELECT
      F1.pid
    FROM
      Fruit AS F1,
      Fruit AS F2
    WHERE
      F1.pid = F2.pid
      AND F1.type = 'apple'
      AND F2.type <> 'banana'
  )
ORDER BY P.pid;
```

However, this is not a strict enough condition, as now I'm allowing for the same fruit type in `F2` as in `F1`, which would still allow that person to be selected. On the other hand I can't restrict this too much, for example with

```sql
F1.type <> F2.type
```

in the subquery, as that would kick out legitimate persons from the `SELECT`ed ones.

What would the restriction have to be to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  P.last_name
FROM
  Person AS P
WHERE
  P.pid IN (
    SELECT
      F1.pid
    FROM Fruit AS F1
      LEFT JOIN Fruit AS F2 ON F2.type = 'banana' AND F1.pid = F2.pid
    WHERE
      F1.type = 'apple'
      AND F2.pid IS NULL

  )
ORDER BY P.pid;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
select p.lastname
from person p
where p.fruit in ('apple', 'banana')
group by p.lastname
having min(p.fruit) = max(p.fruit) and min(p.fruit) = 'apple';
```

The `where` limits the query to only considering apples and bananas.  The `having` clause says that there is only one fruit . . . and that fruit is an apple.

Comment: You possibly also need a `GROUP BY pid`

Answer (score 0):

The main query selects the persons who ate apples.

The `NOT EXISTS` excludes the persons who ate bananas.

```sql
SELECT p.last_name
FROM person p
     INNER JOIN fruit apple ON apple.pid = p.pid
WHERE apple.type = 'apple'
AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM fruit banana
     WHERE banana.pid = p.pid
     AND banana.type = 'banana'
)
```